Android - migration to Kotlin 2.0 causes errors
My Android App was working fine until I started migrating to Kotlin 2.0.
All I changed in the build gradle was:
changing these two lines
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.20" apply false
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.20" apply false

to these:
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "2.0.0" apply false
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "2.0.0" apply false

The AS Compiler settings have Kotlin set to 2.0.0

So that seems fine. But when I update gradle (or try to build) I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization for class
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.VariantFilter: when selecting
method 'com.android.builder.model.ProductFlavor
com.android.build.api.variant.VariantFilter.getDefaultConfig()' the
class loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@4a9dd382 for super interface
com.android.build.api.variant.VariantFilter, and the class loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@6a9d9b6 of the selected method's class,
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.VariantFilter have different
Class objects for the type com.android.builder.model.ProductFlavor
used in the signature (com.android.build.api.variant.VariantFilter is
in unnamed module of loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@4a9dd382, parent loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.CachingClassLoader @6916758b;
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.VariantFilter is in unnamed
module of loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@6a9d9b6, parent loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@4a9dd382)

Try:



Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


Exception is: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization for class
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.VariantFilter: when selecting
method 'com.android.builder.model.ProductFlavor
com.android.build.api.variant.VariantFilter.getDefaultConfig()' the
class loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@4a9dd382 for super interface
com.android.build.api.variant.VariantFilter, and the class loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@6a9d9b6 of the selected method's class,
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.VariantFilter have different
Class objects for the type com.android.builder.model.ProductFlavor
used in the signature (com.android.build.api.variant.VariantFilter is
in unnamed module of loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@4a9dd382, parent loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.CachingClassLoader @6916758b;
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.VariantFilter is in unnamed
module of loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@6a9d9b6, parent loader
org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader
@4a9dd382)    at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.(VariantManager.kt:1023)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$variantManager$2$1.invoke(BasePlugin.kt:235)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$variantManager$2$1.invoke(BasePlugin.kt:233)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AndroidPluginBaseServices.withProject(AndroidPluginBaseServices.kt:307)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$variantManager$2.invoke(BasePlugin.kt:233)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$variantManager$2.invoke(BasePlugin.kt:232)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)  at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.getVariantManager(BasePlugin.kt:232)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$createTasks$1.call(BasePlugin.kt:583)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.NoOpAnalyticsConfiguratorService.recordBlock(NoOpAnalyticsConfiguratorService.kt:54)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.createTasks(BasePlugin.kt:573)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AndroidPluginBaseServices$basePluginApply$4.call(AndroidPluginBaseServices.kt:174)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.NoOpAnalyticsConfiguratorService.recordBlock(NoOpAnalyticsConfiguratorService.kt:54)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AndroidPluginBaseServices.basePluginApply(AndroidPluginBaseServices.kt:169)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$apply$1.run(BasePlugin.kt:350)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting.runAction(crash_reporting.kt:27)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.kt:349)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.kt:129)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:187)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:52)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:282)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:167)
at
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:166)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:146)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:161)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:43)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:98)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:184)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:49)
at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.kt:28)    at
com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.kt:24)     at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:187)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:52)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:282)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:167)
at
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:166)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:137)
at
org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugin$1(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:148)
at
org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:199)
at
org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:146)
at
org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$200(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:60)
at
org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1$1.lambda$add$1(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:119)
at
org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:142)
at
org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:142)
at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:48)
at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:220)
at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:391)
at Program.execute(Unknown Source)  at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:523)
at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.kt:198)
at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator.evaluate(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:121)
at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:51)
at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:48)
at
org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:35)
at
org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at
org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
at
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
at
org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:395)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:413)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:394)
at
org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:46)
at
org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:27)
at
org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:395)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418)
at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418)
at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:394)
at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at


It goes on for many more similar lines.
Any idea what might cause this?

Can you share: 1. your Android Studio version 2. your build.gradle files 3. What gradle and AGP versions you are using ?

Please also properly format the error message in a code block, there is something wrong with the line breaks.

Please share, the scan if possible.

I'm really no expert but I have updated to version kotlin 2.0.0. You may need to remove:
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.2'
}

(or what ever version it is)
Kotlin v2.0.0 removes the need to have the extension version.
